# Cannot add Messages to more than one Azure Queue at the time

Tags: c#, azure, queue

After literally 5 hours of trying I believe that there is something wrong with my Azure Account not letting me work with more than one queue at the time.

I begin by creating two queues with two names in lowercase of course, I then check if they exists and also check their uri names and it seems fine.

Then I begin adding a message to my first queue and this works fine, if I check how many messages the queue has it gives me a number higher than 0.

I then repeat exactly the same steps to add a message to my second queue but this time when I try checking the count of messages, it does not even say 0, it throws null.

If I use getMessage() from the second queue it also returns a null message,  meaning that none of the messages im adding is actually going to the storage in my second queue.

Are there any limitations to this depending on accounts? Do I have to set something differently on azure so that I can have multiple queue partitions working at the same time?

Thank you for your replies in advance..

**EDIT**

Top of my class in a WCF is defined as :

```
private static CloudQueue processedqueue;
private static CloudQueue notprocessedqueue;
```

This is my InitializeStorage method :

```
var queue1 = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
                notprocessedqueue = queue1.GetQueueReference("notprocessedqueue");
                notprocessedqueue.CreateIfNotExist();
var queue2 = account.CreateCloudQueueClient();
                processedqueue = queue2.GetQueueReference("processedqueue");
                processedqueue.CreateIfNotExist();


//I have tried using queue1 to get the reference of both queues but is the same result
```

The method in charge of filling the queues :

```
   var message = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord, processed.ToString()));

    var message2 = new CloudQueueMessage(string.Format("{0},{1}", pWord, processed.ToString()));

processedqueue.AddMessage(message);
notprocessedqueue.AddMessage(message2);



processedqueue.Exists() <- Returns true
processedqueue.Uri.ToString() <- returns a proper URL with the name I defined in the getReference method
notprocessedqueue.Exists() <-  Retruns true 
notprocessedqueue.Uri.ToString() <- returns a proper URL with the name I defined in the getReference method
```

After I executed the addMessage methods I try the following :

```
processedqueue.ApproximateMessageCount <- returns 1
notprocessedqueue.ApproximateMessageCount <- returns null
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the exact same object to the other queue? What happens if you try doing it in the opposite order. I've a feeling some code might be required for a proper answer

Comment: It does work all the way around, that means, changing the order in which I add messages to the queues. And the messages are different, im not trying to add the same message to two queues though currently they hold the same for testing purposes

Comment: Can you show us some code? Generally, this works but depending on how you do it, you can have some problems.

Comment: I added the code I am currently using

Comment: Are you sure you copied the code exactly? Above, it shows two messages being added to `notprocessedqueue`, yet only `processedqueue` showing a message count (and showing a count of 1, though you're adding two messages). I'm sure it's a copy-n-paste error, but this is important to get exactly right, for any type of help to... help.

Comment: Sorry..that is just a typo

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked, what I did was to format the virtual hard drive in which my solution was stored in the worker role, then I clicked on "restore to default" in the azure managament portal, then I restarted the computer and re deployed my solution.

It is working like a charm now,apparently the worker role got bugged somehow.